# Qt Equivalent of NSTokenField

Tags: cocoa, qt, nstokenfield

Is there an equivalent class/method for use in Qt that resembles Cocoa's NSTokenField?

Dan;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  Here's the Qt widget gallery:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/gallery.html

You might be able to achieve a similar effect with a `QTextEdit` and a `QSyntaxHighlighter`, but it's not the same as an NSTokenField.